# jQuery 2 dimensional array - How to loop through it and make a list based on a condition to the array value

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

So here is my 2D array in Jquery.

```
var Codes = [
    $.map($('*[id^="action"]:checked ~ *[id^="product"]'), function (item, idx){
        return $(item).val();
    }),
    $.map($('*[id^="action"]:checked'), function (item, idx) {
        return $(item).val();
    })
];
```

The array is something like this
Codes["Apple"][101], ["Pear"][30] etc.,

I need to make a list of all the codes (eg., 101,1,3) for the product "Apple".

I am pretty new to jquery. Would appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you include no HTML or actual data, we have to guess a little bit from your question, but it looks to me like your declaration of the Codes array creates an array of two arrays where the first array has products in it and the the second array has numbers in it like this:

```
var Codes = [["Apples", "Bananas", "Apples", "Artichokes"], [101, 30, 200, 29]];
```

And you want an array of numbers that correspond to only the Apples entries.  You could do that like this:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Codes[0].length; i++) {
    if (Codes[0][i] == "Apples") {
        results.push(Codes[1][i]);
    }
}
```

Would give this result:

```
results == [101, 200]
```

This assumes that there is exactly one entry in the second array for every element in the first array and that like index items in the first array correspond to that element in the second array.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact result I want. And yes, your assumptions are correct. I tried it, but not getting the desired result.

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8hAA6/.  I corrected one typo in my code - had a [ where I should have had a (.

Comment: My mistake....I corrected the braces and also a typo I had done and it went through giving the expected result. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your array, but try:

```
Codes["Apple"].join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must not have been clear. Would this not create a string with all the codes? I need the result as a one dimensional array or list.